# Prevent updating if no changes were made

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to make a query that updates records if it exists and insert if otherwise.

However if there were no changes were made. I would like to prevent the update command to execute.

Query:

```
MERGE INTO [TESTSRV].[dbo].[COLOR_CODE_PRICE]
USING (Values ('1000','052011','A','20170418','20170430',0.500)) 
AS params(CNS_CUST,COLOR_CODE,INV_ROUTE,START,EXPIRE,PRICE)
ON COLOR_CODE_PRICE.CNS_CUST = params.CNS_CUST
AND COLOR_CODE_PRICE.COLOR_CODE = params.COLOR_CODE
AND COLOR_CODE_PRICE.INV_ROUTE = params.INV_ROUTE
AND (COLOR_CODE_PRICE.PRICE != params.PRICE
OR COLOR_CODE_PRICE.START != params.START
OR COLOR_CODE_PRICE.EXPIRE != params.EXPIRE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET PRICE = params.price, 
           START = params.START, 
           EXPIRE = params.EXPIRE, 
           DATE_MODIFIED = GETDATE(), 
           MODIFIED_BY = 'USER'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (params.CNS_CUST,params.COLOR_CODE,params.INV_ROUTE,params.START,params.EXPIRE,params.PRICE,GETDATE(),NULL,'USER');
```

Table Structure:

[image]

The reason why is I am going to use this query in a VBA macro in Excel.
Retrieve records via `Select` query. Loop through the `Range`.

And For Each row:

- if there are no changes made - Skip updates (to skip modifying `MODIFIED_BY` and other traceability columns)
- if it exists - Insert
- if there are changes - Update

I am successful at Updating and Inserting the records. How can I prevent updates then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `WHEN MATCHED AND source.[Key1] <> target.[Key1] AND source.[Key2]<>target.[Key2] THEN`.

following is the link from MSDN if that helps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql
Please try below query, if it helps:

```
MERGE INTO [TESTSRV].[dbo].[COLOR_CODE_PRICE]
USING (Values ('1000','052011','A','20170418','20170430',0.500)) AS params(CNS_CUST,COLOR_CODE,INV_ROUTE,START,EXPIRE,PRICE)
ON COLOR_CODE_PRICE.CNS_CUST = params.CNS_CUST
AND COLOR_CODE_PRICE.COLOR_CODE = params.COLOR_CODE
AND COLOR_CODE_PRICE.INV_ROUTE = params.INV_ROUTE
AND (COLOR_CODE_PRICE.PRICE != params.PRICE
OR COLOR_CODE_PRICE.START != params.START
OR COLOR_CODE_PRICE.EXPIRE != params.EXPIRE)
WHEN MATCHED AND COLOR_CODE_PRICE.PRICE <>params.price 
        AND  COLOR_CODE_PRICE.START <>params.START 
        AND COLOR_CODE_PRICE.EXPIRE <>params.EXPIRE  THEN
UPDATE SET PRICE = params.price, 
           START = params.START, 
           EXPIRE = params.EXPIRE, 
           DATE_MODIFIED = GETDATE(), 
           MODIFIED_BY = 'USER'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (params.CNS_CUST,params.COLOR_CODE,params.INV_ROUTE,params.START,params.EXPIRE,params.PRICE,GETDATE(),NULL,'USER');
```

Comment: can you provide an example? or better suggest an answer by modifying my query?